# Как приостановить CountDownTimer

Tags: java, android, android-studio, countdowntimer

Цель: сделать паузу в игре-викторине. Я сделал два метода под кнопки:

```
public void pause(View view){
    dialogPause.show();
    onPause();

}

public void resume(View view){
    dialogPause.dismiss();
    onResume();
}
```

Но при нажатии не останавливается таймер. Как это можно реализовать? Вот код таймера:

```
pb = findViewById(R.id.pBar);
    final CountDownTimer tillTheEnd = new CountDownTimer(time, 1000) {
        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            pb.setMax(timing);
            pb.setProgress((int) (millisUntilFinished / 1000));
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            dialogLose.show();
        }
    }.start();
```

Comment: [Здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5738362/pause-countdowntimer-in-android-when-activity-is-not-in-front) предлагают останавливать и создавать новый таймер при каждой паузе.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы не можете приостановить(т.е. поставить на паузу) `CountDownTimer`. Вы можете его лишь остановить методом

```
tillTheEnd.cancel()
```

Но вашу задачу все же можно решить например [так](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10362048/13483092)